# Why does this simple 64-bit/32-bit division algorithm using 32-bit division work?

Tags: c, algorithm, division

I was looking for a 64-bit/32-bit division algorithm preferably with a small code size for a 32-bit x86 machine. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41982320/17665807) surprisingly simple one, but couldn't see how it works.

The algorithm is as follows.

1. We are calculating `x / y` where `x` is 64-bit and `y` is 32-bit. Both are unsigned.
2. `x.l` is the lower bits of `x`, and `x.h` is the higher bits of `x`, assuming a little-endian machine.
3. `h <- x.h / y`
4. `x.h <- x.h % y`
5. `x.l <- x / y, (x.h <- x % y)`; 64-bit/32-bit division only works when the quotient fits in 32 bits, which seems to be true in this case.
6. `x.h <- h`
7. `return x`

My math is just too short to easily get this algorithm. Could you help me to understand this algorithm?

This is a test program I wrote to see if it works.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union {
    uint64_t q;
    struct {
        uint32_t l;
        uint32_t h;
    };
} uint64_u;

uint64_t div_(uint64_t _x, uint32_t y) {
    uint64_u x = {_x};
    uint32_t h = x.h / y;
    x.h = x.h % y;
    __asm__ (
        "div %2":
        "+a" (x.l),
        "+d" (x.h):
        "r" (y)
    );
    x.h = h;
    return x.q;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        uint64_t x = (uint64_t)rand() << 32 | rand();
        uint32_t y = rand() % RAND_MAX + 1;
        uint64_t r0 = x / y;
        uint64_t r1 = div_(x, y);
        if (r0 != r1) {
            abort();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you remember how to do long division by hand?  This is the same, except instead of being base 10, it's base 2^32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is an adaptation of the classic long division method taught in high schools:

- instead of base 10, use base 2<sup>32</sup>
- dividing a 64-bit dividend by a 32-bit divisor is akin to dividing a 2 digit number `A:B` by a one digit number `C`
- take the first *digit* `A` and divide that by the dividend `C`: in `A` goes `D` times `C`, remainder `E`
- take the next *digit* `B`: in `E:B` goes `F` times `C`, remainder `G` (ignored in the code, but could be returned via a pointer)
- the result is `D:F` as constructed in the code.

The code uses a `div` instruction that takes a 64-bit operand EDX:EAX constructed as above from `(x.h % y):(x.l)`.  See https://godbolt.org/z/7x9K8dzsf

A fully portable version, without assembly and using only 32-bit operations is more difficult to write efficiently.